# JavaScript event.target.id return null value on google chrome

Tags: asp.net

I have created a page in this there are some control. on click on text box drop down is viable with suggestion data. my issue is when i click on text box which is visible on screen here JavaScript work perfectly it give target id and shows dropdown which was not viable on screen. now when i click on drop down value and select any data then selected value not populate on textbox because target id return null value. On IE it is working fine.
HTML Page

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
    function pageLoad() {          
        $("#divFlightNumber").show();
        $("#divCourierCompanyName").show();
        $("#divCourierCompanyName").hide();
        //Define variable and assign text object and dropdown object to be used in binding
        var $txtCourierCo = $('input[id$=txtCourierCompanyName]');
        var $ddlCourierCo = $('select[id$=ddlCourierCompanyName]');
        var $itemsCourierCo = $('select[id$=ddlCourierCompanyName] option');
        $("#divFlightNumber").hide();
        //Define variable and assign text object and dropdown object to be used in binding
        var $txtFlightNo = $('input[id$=txtFlightNumber]');
        var $ddlFlightNo = $('select[id$=ddlFlightNumber]');
        var $itemsFlightNo = $('select[id$=ddlFlightNumber] option');  
        $(document).click(function (event) {
            //  debugger;
            var v = event.target.id;
            //alert(v);
            if (v == 'txtFlightNumber') {
                $("#divFlightNumber").show();
                $("#ddlFlightNumber").focus();
                $("#divCourierCompanyName").hide();
                return;                }
            alert(v);
            if (v == 'ctl00_CHDHMenu_ddlFlightNumber') {
                //   debugger;
                selectAndHide('txtFlightNumber', 'ddlFlightNumber', 'divFlightNumber');
                //write code for selectedindex change
                getFlightDetails();
                //$('#ctl00_CHDHMenu_txtDateOfArrival').focus();                    document.getElementById("ctl00_CHDHMenu_txtDateOfArrival").focus();
                return;
            }
            if (v == 'ctl00_CHDHMenu_txtCourierCompanyName') {
                $("#divCourierCompanyName").show();
                $("#divFlightNumber").hide();
                return;
            }
            if (v == 'ctl00_CHDHMenu_ddlCourierCompanyName') {
                selectAndHide('txtCourierCompanyName', 'ddlCourierCompanyName', 'divCourierCompanyName');
                //$("#ctl00_CHDHMenu_txtNumberOfPackages").focus(); 
                document.getElementById("ctl00_CHDHMenu_txtNumberOfPackages").focus();
                return;
            }  
            $("#divFlightNumber").hide();
            $("#divCourierCompanyName").hide();
        });
        $(document).keyup(function (event) {
            var v = event.target.id;
            var keyCode = event.keyCode;
            if (v == 'ctl00_CHDHMenu_txtFlightNumber') {
                searchDdl($txtFlightNo, $ddlFlightNo, $itemsFlightNo, 'divFlightNumber');
                $("#divCourierCompanyName").hide();
                return;
            }
            alert(v);
            if (v == 'ddlFlightNumber') {
                alert(1);
                alert(keyCode);
                if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                    selectAndHide('txtFlightNumber', 'ddlFlightNumber', 'divFlightNumber');
                    //write code for selectedindex change
                    getFlightDetails();
                    //$("#ctl00_CHDHMenu_txtDateOfArrival").focus();
                    document.getElementById("ctl00_CHDHMenu_txtDateOfArrival").focus();
                    return;
                }
                if (event.keyCode == 40 || event.keyCode == 38) { return; }
            }
            if (v == 'ctl00_CHDHMenu_txtCourierCompanyName') {
                searchDdl($txtCourierCo, $ddlCourierCo, $itemsCourierCo, 'divCourierCompanyName');
                $("#divFlightNumber").hide();
                return;
            }  
            if (v == 'ctl00_CHDHMenu_ddlCourierCompanyName') {
                if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                    selectAndHide('txtCourierCompanyName', 'ddlCourierCompanyName', 'divCourierCompanyName');                          document.getElementById("ctl00_CHDHMenu_txtNumberOfPackages").focus();
                    return;
                }
                if (event.keyCode == 40 || event.keyCode == 38) { return; }
            }
            $("#divFlightNumber").hide();
            $("#divCourierCompanyName").hide();
        });  
        $("input[type='text']").click(function () {
            $(this).select();
            $(this).focus();
        });
    }
    function getFlightDetails() {
        var e = document.getElementById("ctl00_CHDHMenu_ddlFlightNumber");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        var Terminalcode = document.getElementById('<%=HdTerminalCode.ClientID %>').value;
        if (strUser != "0") {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "Form1.aspx/GetFlightData",
                data: '{FlightNumber: "' + strUser + '", TerminalCode:"' + Terminalcode + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            }
            );
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("ctl00_CHDHMenu_txtAirlines").value = "";                  document.getElementById("ctl00_CHDHMenu_txtAirportOfArrival").value = "";                document.getElementById("ctl00_CHDHMenu_txtAirportOfShipment").value = "";
            document.getElementById("ctl00_CHDHMenu_txtTimeOfArrival").value = "";                document.getElementById("ctl00_CHDHMenu_txtFlightNumber").focus();
            //return;
        }        }      
</script>
```

Comment: You are using a mix of regular DOM access and jQuery, why not use jQuery throughout and implement error checking throughout...the problem will be a lot easier to find if you test for errors along the way.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].